# How this set can be finite and have theses 4 forms?

Tags: real-analysis, economics

I'm stuck in this paper (**Continuity Properties of Paretian Utility**, Debreu 1964) for a month.

In the point two the author define a **f-set** as a nondegenerate subset A of S such that (a $\in$ A, b $\in$ A, a < b) $\Longrightarrow$ ({c $\in$ S | a $\leqslant$ c $\leqslant$ b} is a *finite* subset of A)

in my head the image of this definition it's something like this:
[image]

after that, this sentence came out and i really don't know what's going on

"Consequently, an f-set necessarily has one of the four forms;

- finite
- a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < ...
- ... < a_-2 < a_-1 < a_0
- ... < a_-1 < a_o < a_1 < ..."

The cases 2, 3 and 4 aren't infinite subsets? how theses are possibles forms of a f-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for an $f$-set can be restated more plainly as "$A$ is an $f$-set if for each pair of elements of $A$ there are finitely many other elements of $A$ between them." It doesn't require $A$ to be finite.

In each of the cases listed at the end of your post, if you pick any two elements of those sets, there are only finitely many elements between them.